# Trying to create and write to file using NSFileHandle... and it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

What am I doing wrong here:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
self.gpsFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString: @"/gpsReadings.txt"];
self.gpsFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:self.gpsFilePath];
[self.gpsFile writeData:@"GPS Readings"];
[self.gpsFile closeFile];
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I need to create the file first:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:self.gpsFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
```

Comment: If only I could so so within 48 hours of posting, I would. Get back to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right way to do:

```
    NSString *chemin = @"fichierlocal";
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:chemin contents:nil attributes:nil];
    NSFileHandle *handle4write = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:chemin];
    NSString *lemessage = @"Hello, World!";
    [handle4write writeData:[lemessage dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [handle4write closeFile];
```

Comment: This adds nothing new to the existing answer.